# Using swfextract to find list of swf's with audio from some 1000+ swf's

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi there I have a requirement to find the number of swf files from some 1000+ swf's with audio. I have tried running **swfextract *.swf > list.txt and it gives the following error "Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two."** How to get it done?!

Answer (score 0):

This is a batch command - Use only one `%` in each `%%a` at the command line.

EDIT: added a `/r` switch to process the current folder recursively for SWF files.

```
for /r %%a in (*.swf) do swfextract "%%a" >> list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive it works!! is there a way to run this command on subfolders too.. as i got swf's in sub folders also.

Comment: hey Got that "for /r %%a in (*.swf) do swfextract "%%a" >> list.txt" but guess  I am doing right.. it does the job though...

Comment: Did you have trouble with it?

Comment: not much the one thing where it digs is, It takes a quite a time to go through 1000+ swf files.apart from that it fine!!

Comment: Ok.  Click on the help on this page and take the `Tour`